# Open source and not for profit alternative to Metacrict and OpenCrict

Tags: pc, nintendo-switch, ps5, xbox

Are there any sites like Metacrict or OpenCricit focused on video games that are open source, provide data easily and are built entirely by the community and not for profit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for some sort of well organized and open database about videogames in general.

If that's the case I'm actually part of a fairly recent endeavour into making an open platform, open source, without profits or monetization, solely focused on keeping track of the history of videogames, be it about best sellings, best reviews, prizes, awards, of all games in all times, in a way thats easily consumable and organizable (csv files).

The project is called: [Open Videogame Data](https://openvideogamedata.github.io).
You can contribute to its growth [here](https://github.com/openvideogamedata/openvideogamedata.github.io).

I really hope this is what you've been looking for!